# SameSite Cookies None problems with Safari browser 14.1

Tags: reactjs, laravel, safari, jwt, samesite

My OS is Mojave 10.16.6, browser Safari 14.1.1.

I ve developed an API with a token-based authentication. The token gets put into a cookie and is than sent to the browser and back to the server until logout. Here is the blog I used as blueprint: https://medium.com/@shindelav/make-an-api-based-application-with-laravel-passport-d6f1074a7b3a

Later I`ve adopted the session.php like this because of the new security policies of several browsers:

**'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true), 'same_site' => "none".**

And the AuthController.php I configured the cookie like this:

**return [ 'name' => '_token', 'value' => $token, 'minutes' => 1440, 'path' => null, 'domain' => null, // 'secure' => true, // for production 'secure' => true, // for localhost 'httponly' => true, 'samesite' => 'None', ];**

Most of browsers do work now (googleChrome etc..) with SameSite=None and Secure=true but safari browser won`t (ok and epic Privacy). Safari won`t sent back the cookie with the token for its security policy.

I came across this discussion: https://gist.github.com/koba04/d52765516600ec51d1761bb0ce994a11

I than turned off "Prevent cross-site tracking" in preferences->privacy and now Safari Browser works too, but this isn`t a sustainable solution. Does anybody have a feasible workaround?

Thx Paul

Comment: What I have neglected to mention is, my frontend and backend have different domains

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: No I haven`t, unfortunately. But I will give it a try some time.